# Why doesn't String.equals() method work inside the JSTL Core tag <c:if>?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, el

Purpose of code: To validate an input string from the user. If the user inputs his name, stored as 'n', as "James" then the message "Validated!" is displayed. 
(A separate HTML form takes care of the input string)

Although there aren't any errors, the test inside the  tag fails and the message is not displayed regardless of whether the input string is "James" or not.

```
<body>

    <%  String n = (String)request.getParameter("n");
           String t = "James";
    %>

    Message <!-- Default message displayed to show that HTML body is read. -->

    <c:if test="${t.equals(n)}"> 
        <c:out value="Validated!"/>
    </c:if>

</body>
```

If I were to replace the test condition with true inside the curly braces, the if condition passes and the message "Validated!" is displayed.

Why doesn't the `equals()` method work inside the JSTL tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You haven't saved your variables to the **scope**.

You've to do this otherwise EL won't see your variables.

Save the variables to *request scope*:

```
<c:set var="n" value="${param.n}" scope="request"/>
<c:set var="t" value="James" scope="request"/>
```

2. 

You need to use EL's **eq** operator instead of Java's `.equals()`.

Change your code like this:

```
<c:if test="${t eq n}"> 
  <c:out value="Validated!"/>
</c:if>
```

P.S. Your JSP file contains scriptlets that is bad practice and the approach is insecure.

Would be even better to separate the logics and the views as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: In order to compare whether two strings are alike, I believe that the equals() method in Java rather than the == operator is used. As far I understand the == operator compares whether the two operands(variables) are referring to the same object. Am I wrong in this?

Comment: I think eq translates to == so my question is still valid. Any case, could you tell me how to compare whether two strings have same value inside the tag?

Comment: @user3111418 If I remember correctly in EL world you are assuming that primitive types doesn't exist (even Beans most often are using wrapping types like `Integer` instead of primitive `int` to allow *unset* state by using null) so `==` is equivalent of `eq` which represents `equals` method.

Comment: Thanks for the link though! It was pretty useful.

Comment: In EL, `eq` and `==` works exactly the same as `.equals()` in Java - it's comparing values of object, not their references to the object.

Comment: @user3111418 Before testing if you can compare values check if EL has them in one of its scopes. You can do it simply by printing them for instance via `n= ${n} t= ${t}`. In your case `<%  String n = (String)request.getParameter("n"); String t = "James"; %>` will not add `n` and `t` to EL scope.

Comment: @user3111418, you told that it still doesn't work. The general reason you could forget to add JSTL libararies to ClassPath and link it to your JSP page. JSTL is extra library, not included to JSP as standart. You use JSTL tags `<c:if>` and `<c:set>` Check this up

Comment: Alright it makes sense! It works now. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use normal `==` comparison operator in this way:

```
<c:if test="${t == n}"> 
    <c:out value="Validated!"/>
</c:if>
```

If you need to compare string values rather than object's attribute, you can do this:

```
<c:if test="${t == 'Any string can be here'}"> 
    <c:out value="Validated!"/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: `n` is variable, not string:)

Comment: What's your suggestion if we need to compare the strings values rather than whether they refer to the same object?